# How to set DefaultLocation of Setup Project to the Path msi is being executed in VS 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have used setup project of VS 2010 to build setup (msi) of one of my application.

I want to install application to the exact location where my msi is. If my msi is in D:\Application folder and someone executes it, it should install the application to that same folder. I know for that I have to go to 
Setup Properties > View > File System > Application Folder.
For Application Folder, I'll have to set DefaultLocation property.

But what should I set as value so that my msi installs the application to the exact location from where it is being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Put [SourceDir] as the default location. That's case-sensitive, as are all Windows Installer properties.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371857(v=vs.85).aspx

I tested this and it works fine. Note that - you'll see the folder name in the browse dialog if you don't hide it, therefore the user could change it.